# Probability of getting the same 3 cards from a 60 card deck?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability of getting the same 3 cards from a 60 card deck?

Order doesn't matter and the cards are placed back into the deck and shuffled between deals. Not the best with probability, so I felt a little uneasy trying to solve this.

My initial thought was it was just two independent cases of [60 choose 3] = 34220²   Making the outcome 1,171,008,400 and the probability 1 / 1,171,008,400.

Not sure if I made a mistake somewhere and don't feel confident in that answer

Comment: So, you draw a card... look at it... shuffle it back into the deck and then draw again, shuffling it back in again, and draw a third time?  Assuming that all cards in the deck are distinct then and assuming I interpreted the question correctly, the case that all three cards match will be $\frac{1}{60}\cdot\frac{1}{60}=\frac{1}{3600}$.

Comment: If you draw three cards., look at them., shuffle them back into the deck and draw three cards again., shuffle back in again and draw three cards a third time., that all three times you draw you have the same hand of three cards will be as you say $\frac{1}{\binom{60}{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{\binom{60}{3}}$

Comment: My apologies for the lack of clarity. I did mean draw 3 cards at once (but only do that a total of two times however I understand where my thinking got off track). Thank you very much for your help

Comment: If you mean to draw 3 cards at once, the accepted answer of 1/3600 is not correct, since it is based on drawing and replacing cards one by one.

Comment: Brett, make sure you change the question description to make it clear, and accept true blue anil's answer since this is the correct one based on what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a close reading of your problem statement, and attempted solution,
I get that $3$ cards are dealt, replaced and shuffled, and the probability you seek is that the same three cards are drawn in the second deal.

Now *any* three cards might have been drawn on the first deal, it doesn't matter which,
only the second deal has to match, so the probability is just $\frac 1{\binom{60}3} = \frac1{34,220}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to make three independent choices.

This means that you choose the first card with a probability of $\frac{60}{60}$.

Then you put it into the deck and draw the second that as a probability of $\frac{1}{60}$ to be equal to the first.

Then you put it into the deck and draw the third that as a probability of $\frac{1}{60}$ to be equal to the first and the second.

At the end you get that the probability of drawing for three times the same card is:
$$1\cdot\frac{1}{60}\cdot\frac{1}{60}=\color{blue}{\frac 1{3600}}$$